# POST a file to VisualForce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I know that it is possible to POST data (text) to VF page and than fetch them through ApexPages.getCurrentPage().getParameters(), but I didn't find a way to do the same if I POST a file and data is multipart/form-data encoded.

This is my piece of sample code:

VF page (page which receive a file after POST)

```
<apex:page controller="PostFile_Controller" sidebar="false" showheader="false"  applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false" cache="false" action="{!react}">

</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class PostFile_Controller {

    public PageReference react() {

        //get all parameters
        system.debug(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters());

        //get all headers
        system.debug(ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders());
    }   
}
```

VF page which POST a file (this is just an example, I actually use jquery file upload plugin (http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/):

```
var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
$.ajax({
    url: '/apex/postfile',  //Server script to process data
    type: 'POST',
    xhr: function() {  // Custom XMLHttpRequest
    var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
    return myXhr;
    },
    // Form data
    data: formData
});
```

Do you have any ideas what I am doing wrong or it is completely impossible to achieve that?

Comment: try posting to the true url c.cs2.visual.force.com instead of cs2.salesforce.com (replace with your instance) as suggested on this discussion thread https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F0000000958DIAQ

Comment: Parameter url: '/apex/postfile' is relative which means that when POST happens from VF page c.cs2.visual.force.com/apex/testformupload url '/apex/postfile' transforms to c.cs2.visual.force.com/apex/postfile.